# Pytest - is there a way to not have to re write a test function three times?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Is there a way to not have to re write this test function three times? Maybe a `fixture` so I can use a param / arg?

Tank you ever so much for reading.

```py
from kingarthur import data
from pathlib import Path


def test_BuildZoneA():
    zone_path = Path('home/stevethewizard/zoneA.txt')
    data.BuildZone('t', 's', zone_path, source_list=['spell1', 'spell2'])
    assert zone_path.is_file() == True
    assert zone_path.stat().st_size > 0


def test_BuildZoneB():
    zone_path = Path('home/stevethewizard/zoneB.txt')
    data.BuildZone('t', 's', zone_path, cust_source_path='home/stevethewizard/spells/spells_master.txt')
    assert zone_path.is_file() == True
    assert zone_path.stat().st_size > 0


def test_BuildZoneC():
    zone_path = Path('home/stevethewizard/zoneC.txt')
    data.BuildZone('t', 's', zone_path)
    assert zone_path.is_file() == True
    assert zone_path.stat().st_size > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/), you can parametrize your tests using [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html). For example:

```
import pytest

from kingarthur import data
from pathlib import Path

@pytest.mark.parametrize("zone_path,source_list,source_path", [
  (Path("/home/stevethewizard/ZoneA.txt"), ['spell1', 'spell2'], None),
  (Path("/home/stevethewizard/ZoneB.txt"), None, ".../spells_master.txt"),
  (Path("/home/stevethewizard/ZoneC.txt"), None, None),
])
def test_BuildZone(zone_path, source_list, source_path):
    data.BuildZone('t', 's', zone_path, source_list=source_list, cust_source_path=source_path)
    assert zone_path.is_file() == True
    assert zone_path.stat().st_size > 0
```

Read the linked documentation for more information.

Comment: Took me a moment to follow because you only renamed `cust_source_path` and I kept looking for the reason. Then I realized there wasn't one. LOL Thanks for the response. What if I wanted that parameter piece to not have hard coded values? Is that even possible? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you want instead of hardcoded values?

Comment: I was just wondering if you could put args in instead.

Comment: I'm *still* not sure what you're asking. Those are "arguments". They don't need to be static arguments -- it's just Python, so of course they could be functions that return something instead of static values. For testing you typically *want* static values so that you get consistent test results.

Comment: I'm looking at it in terms of source control. I wouldn't want hard coded values there and they get committed / pushed. But rather have another module or file that is included in the gitignore that provides the values.

Comment: Sure, you could do that.

Comment: RIght, I know I can do it. I am asking for a common method. Is the most common way to create like a `const.py` in and then variables. Then call them in the above like `const.POWERPATHFIVETHOUSAND`? Or is there a more proper way with pytest? Like a conftest.py?

Comment: I think that's a reasonable method. I'm not sure if it's common or not. I generally use hardcoded values for simple tests or variables defined elsewhere in the same module for larger data structures, but I'm sure other folks do exactly what you've proposed.

Comment: Thanks, big dog. I'd upvote you a million times if I could.  Maybe you could do me a solid and upvote me once. Thanks again. I just realized you worked at Redhat. Fedora is the best homelab OS ever! And Redhat rulez! I'll use that buy me a coffee link.